# (ASP.NET) sending JWT over https

Tags: asp.net, https, jwt

I would like to use the following architecture for a ASP.NET Webserver that must be able to provide authentication to multiple distant clients :

Client <===[GET/POST]===> Server (ASP.NET)

The authentication will be done by using a JWT signed using a SHA512 encryption.

To avoid MIM attack, I would like to force all JWT exchange through HTTPS only.

**First question : is it a good idea to use encrypted JWT ? Are there any better solution (better in terms of security)**

In the ASP.NET doc --> [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu), they recommend to use the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` function and provide an https port in the appsetting.json file : `"https_port": 443,`

But I am wondering about this `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` function.

When a client send a request over http, I understand that the server will redirect the request to https (and probably redirect also the answer, if any, to https?)

**Second question : What about the initial (http) request? Because as far as I know, this initial request contains already all the jwt header & payload. Before the redirection, the request is thus sent whithout any encryption... Or I am misunderstanding...?**

Then, I have read some articles about the use of a session ID that is exchanged in the JWT payload in place of username, emails and things like that. This session ID is stored in a database and managed by the server.

**Third question : I assume that this is better only if the JWT is not ecnrypted to avoid an attacker to stole the payload content, but is it necessary/better when a JWT is exchanged through https?**

Thanks for any help or advice about this ;)